# How to return table data from home view Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm sure this is a novice question, but troubling me for awhile now.

I have a testimonials table and I'm trying to output a few testimonials on the home page.

This is what I have going on.

**Route:(web.php)**

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

**Home Controller:**

```php
use DB;
use App\Testimonial;
...
public function index()
{
    $testimonial = DB::table('testimonials')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('home', compact('testimonials'));
}
```

**Home View / Blade:**

```php
@foreach ($testimonial as $test)
<h4>{{$test->first_name}}</h4>
<p>{{$test->testimonial}}</p>
@endforeach
```

**Error:**

> Undefined variable: testimonial

Any insight on this issue would be helpful.

Comment: Sanity check: Which route are you seeing this error? Are you visiting `/` or `/home`? Because both use the same view, but you're only passing data into `/home`. You're not passing anything on `/`.

Comment: From your original question, another alternative to the selected answer is to use `return redirect("/home");` instead of `return view("home");` in your `routes/web.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route for '/' goes directly to the 'home' view without passing through the controller.  Changing that route to go to the same controller method will fix it.

```php
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

The variable names also need to match in the controller and view.

**Controller**

```php
use DB;
use App\Testimonial;
...
public function index()
{
    $testimonials = DB::table('testimonials')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
    return view('home', compact('testimonials'));
}
```

**View**

```php
@foreach ($testimonials as $test)
    <h4>{{$test->first_name}}</h4>
    <p>{{$test->testimonial}}</p>
@endforeach
```

That should work, assuming your database query is actually returning results.  If it still isn't working, try checking what is in the $testimonials variable after it is assigned.

```php
dd($testimonials);
```

Comment: I wish it was that, but I have `$testimonial = DB::table...` in the Controller and `$testimonial as $test` in the view. Both are singular. I tried making both plural as you suggested, but no change.

Comment: I just noticed the problem in the controller and updated my answer.  The compact function is a way to send the variable to the view as a key => value pair. So `compact('testimonials')` is the same as doing `['testimonials' => $testimonials]`.

Comment: Man... Still keep getting `Undefined variable: testimonials` Is it something to do with the routes you think?

Comment: I just looked at your routes.  The base page URL route (without the '/home') returns the view but doesn't run through the controller and doesn't load the data.  Is that the page you are visiting?  Does it work if you visit '/home' ?

Comment: yep.. If I go to /home it outputs the testimonial data. How would I get it to run through the base page without the route?

Comment: The easiest way is to just point that route to the same controller method. `Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Please update your answer and I'll close this thread. I sure feel like a doofus.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning wrong variable, change your return like this:

```php
return view('home', compact('testimonial'));
```

Everything is fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable is called `$testimonial`, you should pass:

```php
// singular testimonial
return view('home', compact('testimonial'));
```

Then, you can use:

```php
@foreach ($testimonial as $test)
```